# Mysql PAM authentication

Tags: linux, mysql, pam

Is it possible for mysql to use PAM (or NIS) authentication. I want to allow all users from unix XXX group to be able to connect to mysql and do whatever they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately mysql doesn't support any kind of PAM authentication, you can use MySQL as a backend for PAM auth but no the other way around.

You'll have to create some kind of script/trigger/puppet recipe to add a new user to the mysql server everytime a new user is added to the PAM database

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible with [MySQL External Authentication for PAM](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/security.html) but I haven't tried yet.

([MySQL version > 5.5](http://blogs.oracle.com/MySQL/entry/new_commercial_extensions_for_mysql))